# How to get only matching data from three tables

Tags: sql-server

Main Table: `Select * from Table1`

```
Id  Name1 Name2

101  ttt  sss
```

Second Table : `Select * from Table2`

```
SId  Id  Colum1 Column2  Column3

1    101  hhh     xxx    erre

2    101  wsa     tgf     fdfd
```

Third Table: `Select * from Table3`

```
TId  Id   TColumn1  Tcolumn2

5    101   uyt       uyu
```

My Query:

```
Select * from Table1 t1
Join Table2 t2 on t2.Id= t1.Id
Join Table3 t3 on t3.Id= t1.Id
```

I am geeting Data like this

```
 Id  Colum1 Column2  Column3  TColumn1  Tcolumn2

 1   hhh     xxx    erre      uyt          uyu

 2   wsa     tgf     fdfd     uyt          uyu
```

What I want is of My data

```
 Id  Colum1 Column2  Column3  TColumn1  Tcolumn2

 1   hhh     xxx    erre      uyt          uyu

 2   wsa     tgf    fdfd     null         null
```

Comment: DId you already try to use "Left Outer Join" instead of "Join"?

Comment: Is the rule is that - always have NULL for all except the 1st row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below query

```
 ; with cte as 
    (
    Select 
    Colum1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    TColumn1,
    Tcolumn2,
    row_number () over(partition by t2.id order by SId asc) r
    from Table1 t1
    Join Table2 t2 on t2.Id= t1.Id
    Join Table3 t3 on t3.Id= t1.Id
    )

Select 
Colum1,
Column2,
Column3,
TColumn1 =case when r=1 then TColumn1 else NULL end,
Tcolumn2 =case when r=1 then Tcolumn2 else NULL end
from cte
```

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/YWMPK41463)**</kbd>